# Trying to get property of non-object In schedule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel 5.5 and I want to schedule a task,I have tried with below code

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $data = MenterRequest::where('menter_subscriber_id','=',$user_id)->first();
    $sentTime  =  $data->created_at;
    $currentTime = Carbon::now();
    $diff_in_hours = $sentTime->diffInHours($currentTime);
    if($diff_in_hours >=75)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('menter_requests')->where('menter_subscriber_id','=',$user_id)->delete();
        })->everyMinute();
    }

}
```

If tried to get auth user id im getiing  **Trying to get property of non-object** Error,User is already authenticated or logged In .

Comment: Which line is causing the error? It might not be `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: @SteD In the first line getting error,where Im trying to get auth user ID.

Comment: @SteD is there any other method to get current logged in user ID??

Comment: ok, let's try `dd(Auth::user())` , what you get?

Comment: @SteD getting NULL

Comment: can I have a look at your route file? did you include `web` and `auth` as middleware?